# Accessing private members of a class

Tags: c++

I'm new to classes I created a new class to track different details of an account however I was told that the members of my class should be private and to use a getter and setter function. I have look a lots of examples but I can't seem to figure out how to access the private members from my main program. I want the user to enter the different parameters for the account if I make the members public it works just fine how do I add the getters and setters. the private members of my class and whats in main is the only stuff that I need everything else I was adding to try to make it work but i'm really lost. Im using the vector because once i get it to work i'll write a loop to get the data for multiple accounts but right now i'm just trying to get the input stored

```
class account

{  public            
       friend void getter(int x);

   private:
       int a;
       char b;
       int c;
       int d;
};

using namespace std;

void  getter (int x)
{

}

int main()
{
  vector <account> data1 (0);
  account temp;

  cin>>temp.a>>temp.b>>temp.c>>temp.d;
  data1.push_back(temp);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Who told you to use getters and setters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a friend operator overload:

```
class account
{
    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &, account &);
public:
    // ...
};

std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, account& ac)
{
    return is >> ac.a >> ac.b >> ac.c >> ac.d;
}

int main()
{
    account temp;

    std::cin >> temp;
}
```

Comment: @JesseWashington Do `std::cin >> temp;` like I have.

Comment: okay i know what operator over loading is and i have pretty good understanding of what the code is doing. i am familiar with using the & on the end of data types to pass them by reference but why is it by itself ex. (std::istream &, account &); but later on its (std::istream& is, account& ac). oh btw its working now thanks

Comment: @JesseWashington Good, I'm glad it's working. The first is simply a prototype of the function so the argument names are optional. I only give the arguments names when I need to use them (e.g when I am implementing the function).

Comment: so i could change the operator>> to + like              std::istream& operator+ (std::istream& is, account& ac)
{
    return is >> ac.a >> ac.b >> ac.c >> ac.d;
}                                                                    and then use cin+temp;

Comment: i know this isnt practical just trying to learn how to work with this new stuff

Comment: @Tjarmws Yeah, that would work, but I wouldn't do that. I like to keep everything as semantic as possible. :)

Comment: @Tjarmws You just have to make sure it's a friend function otherwise `std::cin + temp` will give an error because it can't access the private data members.

Comment: now im trying to output the data                             ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, account& ad)
{
    return get<< ad.a <<ad.b <<ad.c <<ad.d;
}                                                                   i thought this should work but its not i need to be able to output cout<<"The account has"<<ad.a<<" many people.                      or write an if statment if (ad.c>5){...........} now im kinda back at the beginning with the same scope error so should i use the get() function from the other post or is there another way

Comment: It should be `return os << …` not `return get << …`. And when you're in main it should be `std::cout << "blah" << ad`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of get/set methods:

```
class account

{  public            
       int getA() const { return a; }
       void setA(int new_value) { a = new_value; }
       int getB() const { return b; }
       void setB(int new_value) { b = new_value; }
       int getC() const { return c; }
       void setC(int new_value) { c = new_value; }
       int getD() const { return d; }
       void setD(int new_value) { d = new_value; }

   private:
       int a;
       char b;
       int c;
       int d;
};
```

From the main you would use:

```
int main()
{
  vector <account> data1 (0);
  account temp;
  int a,b,c,d;

  cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
  temp.setA(a);
  temp.setB(b);
  temp.setC(c);
  temp.setD(d);
  data1.push_back(temp);

  return 0;
}
```

NOTE: Whether having get/set methods in a case like this is a good idea is another issue.

Comment: so how does that work with cin>>temp.a>>temp.b>>temp.c>>temp.d; i still get the error cannot access private members a b c and d;

Comment: @JesseWashington: I've added an example.

Comment: @JesseWashington It looks like you're misunderstanding the purpose of a getter: it's a public method that you can call to return the value of a private member value. As is pointed out in Vaughn Cato's example.

Comment: would it be temp.setA(b); temp.setA(c); or would i have to write a function for every class member. I mad them all ints for my example but i really have strings and other data types so if i had a class with 7 different members would i have to write 7 different get and set functions?

Comment: @JesseWashington: You have to write a get/set for each.  I've extended my example.

Comment: -1. You don't *have* to write get/set methods. Please don't encourage this style of programming. Overload `operator>>` for much better encapsulation instead.

Comment: Seriously, if you are doing this, just make the damn things public. Save your wrists.

Comment: @TemplateRex: The question was about how to do it, not whether it was a good idea.

Comment: @Martinho i know i could just make them public but i want to learn how to use a class correctly. i know it has public private and protected members but if i never learn how to use them how can i write higher level code or read someones code that did use them

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I agree.  I certainly wouldn't use get/set members in a case like this, but based on the question, it was a given that it needed to be done.  "I was told that the members of my class should be private and to use a getter and setter function."  Maybe it was an exercise.

Comment: i see how you got that from readin my orginal post i just read it again. the main thing was accessing the private members which ever way i could find to do it the best. someone i was asking told me about getter and setters and i went with that cause i had no other place to start from.

Comment: @Tjarmws to paraphrase Scott Meyers:  "Frankly, if you're hanging out with people who tell you to use getters and setters, you need to rethink your social circle."